# Having trouble going from codepen to website

Tags: javascript, typeerror, codepen

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I have code loaded in codepen and it works fine. I am trying to put it in my website and it is not working.

The code is from https://github.com/technotarek/timeliner. 
My website platform: zoho sites.
Code pen: [here](https://codepen.io/CaRo14/pen/yxWmaZ) *UPDATE: This is the codepen where jQuery is loaded and everything works.*

With a code snippet, I'm using the following code format:

style
html
script

I put the following in the header section of the site:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/CaRo14/pen/eLwOmZ) is a code pen of what my code snippet looks like. *UPDATE: This codepen reflects what I used in the code snippet and does not include the jQuery loader.*

Here is my error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.timeliner is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (contact:9)
    at c (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.H (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I think my problem has something to do with the fact that the original code called for a  in the html and a JS file. I combined the two. Like I siad, it works in codepen, but I havent worked too much with JS.  I am lost.

Comment: Are you sure it works on codepen? I'm getting the same error there.

Comment: sorry, yes, getting same error re timeliner (wrong codepen in my previous comment)

Comment: I am also getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).venobox is not a function` and few 404 errors. Not sure how you defined a function. Can you include this `venobox` method ?

Comment: SO do not encourage to use `Codepen` you can paste your code here with option attach HTML/JS/CSS ,its better to add code in your question to get more clarity

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank's for your contribution. According the [How to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) we'd appreciate if you integrate the essential *correct* parts of code in your question. High quality questions are more likely to get up-votes too. The current state where you've to explain links on external sites is considered very bad. Thanks!

Comment: in the part of the code that does `$(document).ready(function() {
   $.timeliner({
    timelineContainer:'#timeline',
   });
   $('.venobox').venobox();
  });` - jquery version is 3.1.1

Where you are `$.timeliner = function(options) {` ... jquery version is 1.9.1

You have to be careful when using multiple versions of jquery

Comment: In codepen - The various dates expand to reveal the content when I click on expand or when I click on a date. That is what leads me to believe it works on codepen.

Comment: Reading back over this, I should also mention, the JS script has not been loaded in the second codepen link (the one that shows what my code snippet looks like. That link only shows what is actually pasted in the code snippet. 

The first codepen link (Code pen: here) has everything loaded.

Comment: @David - I tried to include the actual code in the question; however, I got an error that it was too long. That is why I included links to the code with codepen. In an attempt to facilitate a quick response, I also included links to the working codepen and a codepen showing what the HTML, CSS, and JS looks like integrated into one file. I'm not sure how I could have formulated a better question given the restrictions on length.